# Adding a new Filter in the chain

Tags: jhipster

I want to add a new servlet filter in the JHipster chain. It is one that needs to execute **after** a JWT has been deemed valid. Basically I want this new filter to check a "balance" repository for the current user and to return a HTTP 402 code if the balance is insufficient.

I had thought of adding it after the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter(which comes after the JWTFilter) via a BalanceConfigurer

```
    public BalanceConfigurer() {

    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) {
        BalanceFilter balanceFilter = new BalanceFilter();
        http.addFilterAfter(balanceFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```

does that seem correct ?

Comment: If im not mistaken filters are fixed to always return 401 on an error ? Might a better idea to be to create an Aspect and attach it to the relevant controllers.. have it check the balance before the method .. throw a InsufficentBalanceException when it makes sense and then catch this in the 'after' of the aspect and transate to a Http 402 code ?

Comment: Given that you want to execute code after JWT authentication and before controller, have you considered using a HandlerInterceptor? It's like an Aspect but simpler. See https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-handlerinterceptor-vs-filter

Comment: yes.. thats actually what I ended up doing much simpler.. https://github.com/walshe/bolt11-lightning-monitized-api-/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/mycompany/myapp/interceptor/BalanceInterceptor.java

Answer (score 1):

It was much easier to add a `BalanceInterceptor` - an impl of `org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerInterceptor` which also allowed me to  figure out the actual api that was being invoked (which I couldn't do with an aspect on the controller )